# im trying to make whenever you hover over a list item the frame source changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make an IFrame and whenever you hover over a champion it changes the source of the frame to the champion's page, so this is the ul:

```
<ul id="myUL" class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 60px;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 100px;height: 100%">
```

this is the iframe:

```
<iframe id="jaiframe" style="height: 1100px;margin-left: 60px;width: 1000px;margin-top: 1000px;"></iframe>
```

and this is one of the `<il>`s

```
<li style="text-align: right;"><div class="col-md-10"></div><a href="champs/Aatrox.html" class="champ"><div class="col-md-1" id="champ" >
              <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/leagueoflegends/images/c/cc/AatroxSquare.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/48?cb=20160417012601">
              </div><div class="col-md-1" id="champ" >Aatrox</div></a></li>
```

this is my js linking:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

this is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myUL li').hover(function() {
        $('#jaiframe').attr('src', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
   });
});
```

I've also tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul#myUL li').hover(function() {
    $('#jaiframe').attr('src', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
   });
});
```

instead

Comment: what's the issue? what does the current code do?

Comment: It doesnt do anything

Comment: whenever I hover on a list item it doesnt change at all

Comment: could you make a http://jsfiddle.net that reproduces the issue?

Comment: how do I send you the jsfiddle link? do I need to sign up to jsfiddle to get a sharing link?

Comment: Are the relative paths of those `href` valid within the scope of an iframe?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arqeu01u/1/

Comment: Yeah, they should be @charlietfl

Comment: Too much code in that demo...scale it down to a [mcve] ...just enough to display the problem and no more. Doesn't require much css either

Comment: Missing closing tags at linked jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arqeu01u/7/ changed it

Comment: Well now you haven't even looked at errors thrown....jQuery.js isn't even included

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arqeu01u/9/ closed the tags sry for that i couldnt see them, it's not in my real code though

Comment: I linked it in my original script but jsfiddle told me i dont need to, dunno

Comment: With valid `html` `javascript` at Question returns expected result.

Comment: @guest271314 it works for you? so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given `html`, `javascript` at Question not certain. Protocol of `iframe` should match protocol of original `window.location.href`.

Comment: Have you thought about adding some `console.log()` calls to verify that your JavaScript is doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: oh right I'm gonna try it now thank you!@Pointy im just not very good with js

Comment: I get this : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?

Comment: That's because either jQuery is not available or `$` alias has been removed by `jQuery.noConflict()` or you try to use `$` before it is available. In the demo you didn't even include it

Comment: yea I had to load jQuery before, didn't know that, my apologise.